# How do I configure paths to my javascript files in the Jasmine / Maven autogenerated ManualSpecRunner.html?

Tags: javascript, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, jasmine

I think the question says most of it.  I have an autogenerated ManualSpecRunner.html file as created by maven / jasmine plug-in and I've got it to put itself into the deployable .war by using:

```
<jasmineTargetDir>${basedir}/pathForMyWebapp</jasmineTargetDir>
```

However, all the links to js files within the ManualSpecRunner.html are hard coded file:/// references - this is a bit mental, I want them to just be the relative paths to the files that are also in the webapp i.e.

Currently it gives me this path:

```
file:///home/username/code/HEAD/pathForMyWebapp/js/yui.js
```

whereas I need it to have the far more simple

```
/pathForMyWebapp/js/yui.js
```

I have tried changing two other variables in the maven script, but neither seems to have the desired effect, neither of these configuration options do what I need, the second having seemingly no effect:

```
<jsSrcDir>/pathForMyWebapp</jsSrcDir>
```

nor

```
<jsTestSrcDir>/pathForMyWebapp</jsTestSrcDir>
```

I've looked through the documentation but think I must be missing something (also, more notes on various config params listed in https://github.com/searls/jasmine-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/searls/jasmine/AbstractJasmineMojo.java are meant to do would be helpful so I can work out if I'm doing it wrong or if it's not possible!)

Any suggestions?

[p.s. I've changed some of the path names as they've got sensitive info in them, so please ignore their oddness!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand the source of your confusion. It looks like you're trying to direct the target of the jasmine-maven-plugin to a directory *inside* your project's packaged *.war file so that you can run your specs against the code after it's deployed to a server, is that correct?

Unfortunately, the plugin wasn't designed with that use in mind. The `jasmineTargetDir` directory is usually left at its default value of `target/jasmine` and wasn't intended to be bundled with your application (it's analogous to the `target/surefire-reports` generated by maven-surefire-plugin for Java unit tests). So the reason that the script tags in `ManualSpecRunner.html` point to invalid locations is because that file is generated in order to be run from the local filesystem in a browser from the workstation that's building the project (to facilitate TDD).

All of that to say, if I'm reading your intention right, I think it'd be a cool feature to build a third spec runner that could be deployed with the app and executed remotely. (Especially if the project's Jasmine specs are functional/integration as opposed to isolated unit tests.) Unfortunately that's not something the project does yet.

I'm afraid that for now, if you needed to bundle the jasmine tests and execute them on the deployed server, you would need to copy `ManualSpecRunner.html` and jasmine into your `src/main/webapp`, fix the script tag references, and then manually maintain it as files are added and removed.

Make sense?

Comment: Many thanks for this - yes that does indeed make sense.  Shame I can't faff with it to make it use relative paths in the spec runner, but I look forward to that in the future ;)     Thanks again for this answer!  CJ